# How to animate and update the horizontal axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to display some "live" data. Preferably, I would like to have the horizontal axis display a running interval over the most recent 10 seconds or so.

The program below demonstrates what I'm after. However, this program doesn't do what I want in two ways.

First, I'd like the horizontal axis to display absolute time (currently, it displays time, in seconds, relative to "tNow"). The horizontal axis should ideally be continuously updated.

Second, for some reason I don't understand, the first evaluations of the signals drawn are persistent; I am only interested in the "moving" signal; the static signal is an artifact. How can I get rid of it?

I am unfortunately not terribly good with matplotlib. Therefore, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import time

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_line(num, line1, line2):

    tNow = time.time()

    t = np.linspace(tNow - 10.0, tNow, 200)

    f1 = 0.5 # Hz
    f2 = 0.3 # Hz

    line1.set_data(t - tNow, np.sin(2 * np.pi * f1 * t))
    line2.set_data(t - tNow, np.sin(2 * np.pi * f2 * t))

    return (line1, line2)

(fig, axes_list) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

axes1 = axes_list[0]
axes2 = axes_list[1]

line1, = axes1.plot([], [], 'r-')
line2, = axes2.plot([], [], 'b-')

for ax in [axes1, axes2]:
    ax.set_xlim(-10, 0)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    #ax.set_xlabel('x')
    #ax.set_ylabel('y')
    #ax.set_title('test')

animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, 250, fargs = (line1, line2), interval = 0, blit = True)

# Enter the event loop
fig.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'absolute time'? Time of day? `tNow`?

Comment: Time of day. Currently the time is displayed relative to tNow. I'd like to see actual wallclock times on the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it a little differently. However, I'm not sure if this is the best way. Comments and suggestions are welcome

```
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

F1 = 0.5 # Hz
F2 = 0.3 # Hz

def update_line(tstart, axes):

    for ax in axes:
        # Remove old lines
        ax.lines.pop()

    # Plot new lines
    axes[0].plot(t, np.sin(2 * np.pi * F1 * np.array(t)), 'r-')
    axes[1].plot(t, np.sin(2 * np.pi * F2 * np.array(t)), 'b-')

# relabel the x tick marks to be absolute time
def show_abs_time(abs_start, axes):

    for ax in axes:
        tick_labels = []
        ticks = ax.get_xticks()

        # using the relative time for each tick mark, add it to the absolute time
        for rel_time in ticks:
            abs_time = abs_start + datetime.timedelta(0,rel_time) 
            tick_labels.append(abs_time.strftime("%X"))

        ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plt.ion()
    plt.close("all")

    (fig, axes) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

    # Initial Plot configuration 
    for ax in axes:
        ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
        ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
        ax.set_xlabel('x')
        ax.set_ylabel('y')
        ax.set_title('test')

    tstart = time.time()
    delta_t = 0
    t = []
    abs_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.strftime("%X"), "%H:%M:%S")  

    axes[0].plot([], [], 'r-')
    axes[1].plot([], [], 'b-')

    plt.show()

    while delta_t < 20 :

        tNow = time.time()
        delta_t = tNow - tstart
        t.append(delta_t)
        update_line(t, axes)

        # Once your time extends past a certain point, update the x axis
        if delta_t > 9:
            for ax in axes:
                ax.set_xlim(delta_t-9,delta_t + 1)

        # redo the x ticks to be absolute time
        show_abs_time(abs_start, axes)

        # update the plots
        plt.draw()
```